# disable bootstrap dl-horizontal class for responsive window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I design list using bootstrap and `dl-horizontal` class like this :

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>1</dt>  <dd>deta1</dd>
  <dt>1</dt>  <dd>deta1</dd>
  <dt>1</dt>  <dd>deta1</dd>
  <dt>1</dt>  <dd>deta1</dd>
  <dt>1</dt>  <dd>deta1</dd>
  <dt>1</dt>  <dd>deta1</dd>
  <dt>1</dt>  <dd>deta1</dd>
  <dt>1</dt>  <dd>deta1</dd>
  <dt>1</dt>  <dd>deta1</dd>
</dl>
```

This work and show list in large desktop. But, when i resize window and check windows for responsive design `dd` show in below of `<dt>`. i need to show `dd` opposite of `dt` in all window. how do can i fix this?

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/upth949Zco)

Comment: What the f***!? This code works just fine on my localhost but it doesn't on jsfiddle... okay, what's going on :P

Answer (score 2):

@GusRuss89 is right: it's in a media query. But instead of copying the CSS, you should change the `@dl-horizontal-breakpoint` variable.

```
  @media (min-width: @dl-horizontal-breakpoint) {
    dt {
      float: left;
      width: (@dl-horizontal-offset - 20);
      clear: left;
      text-align: right;
      .text-overflow();
    }
    dd {
      margin-left: @dl-horizontal-offset;
    }
  }
}
```

I've changed `@dl-horizontal-offset` to `400px` and now the term and definition of the list are on one row.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS for .dl-horizontal is in a media query. You can simply copy it out of there and add it to your normal CSS. This looks like it should be all you need.

You may want to reduce the width of the `dt` and left margin of the `dd` to fit better on smaller screens.

```
.dl-horizontal dt {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dl-horizontal dd {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```